# space between specific rows in a table

Tags: tables, spacing

This script

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
%{\def\arraystretch{2}                                                                                                                                                                       
  \begin{tabular}{l r }
    aa00                  & bb00                \\
    aa11                  & bb11                \\
    aa22                  & $\frac{1}{9}$       \\
    aa33                  & $\frac{1}{9}$       \\
    aa44                  & $\frac{1}{9}$       \\
    aa55                  & bb55
  \end{tabular}
%  }                                                                                                                                                                                                        
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

renders the output

[image]

The fractions bump into each other that suggests that the space between the respective rows should be expanded.

In this example I try using `\def\arraystretch{2}` as in [How to set the space between rows in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102996/how-to-set-the-space-between-rows-in-a-table?answertab=active#tab-top) but this recipe applies to the whole table. How to achieve the same just for select rows?

Comment: Have you tried something as simple as `\\[1ex]`?

Comment: Did you consider using inline-fraction notation, i.e., writing `1/9`, instead of `\frac` notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution, in my opinion, uses the `cellspace` package, which enables you to define a *minimal* vertical padding at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C`, if you load `siunitx`). Here is a demo:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{cellspace, amsmath}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
   \begin{tabular}{l Sr }
    aa00 & bb00 \\
    aa11 & bb11 \\
    aa22 & $\frac{1}{9}$ \\
    aa33 & $\frac{1}{9}$ \\
    aa44 & $\frac{1}{9}$ \\
    aa55 & bb55
  \end{tabular}
\hspace{4em}
   \begin{tabular}{l Sr }
    aa00 & bb00 \\
    aa11 & bb11 \\
    aa22 & $\dfrac{1}{9}$ \\
    aa33 & $\dfrac{1}{9}$ \\
    aa44 & $\dfrac{1}{9}$ \\
    aa55 & bb55
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Inline-fraction notation was invented for a very good (typographic) reason: to display simple fraction expressions without needing to increase the row spacing. So, do consider switching from `\frac` notation to inline-fraction notation. The table on the right use `1/9` instead of `\frac{1}{9}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
  \begin{tabular}{l r }
    aa00                  & bb00                \\
    aa11                  & bb11                \\
    aa22                  & $\frac{1}{9}$       \\
    aa33                  & $\frac{1}{9}$       \\
    aa44                  & $\frac{1}{9}$       \\
    aa55                  & bb55
  \end{tabular}
\qquad
  \begin{tabular}{l r }
    aa00                  & bb00        \\
    aa11                  & bb11        \\
    aa22                  & $1/9$       \\
    aa33                  & $1/9$       \\
    aa44                  & $1/9$       \\
    aa55                  & bb55
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```