# Consistent vertical padding in tabular for inline \displaystyle math and normal text

Tags: tables

I am making a table with displaystyle inline math, and am having trouble getting a consistent vertical spacing between each row.

[image]

To be clear, I want the vertical padding for the fraction to be the same as that of the gobbledygook. I have tried using `\def\arraystretch{...}`, but it doesn't produce a consistent spacing.

The solutions in [How to set the space between rows in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102996/how-to-set-the-space-between-rows-in-a-table) don't really seem to solve this problem generally.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
Gobbledygook\\
\hline
$\displaystyle\frac{a}{b}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pad the cell contents, eg

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\pad[1]{{\fboxsep=.5em \fboxrule=0pt \fbox{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
\pad{Gobbledygook}\\
\hline
\pad{$\displaystyle\frac{a}{b}$}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems that the command does not preserve line wrapping, is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: @Pseudonym123 you had a `c` column which has no line wrapping, so there is nothing to preserve.

Comment: I was actually using tabularx with an X column, but simplified it to just a tabular environment for the question because I thought they'd behave the same. Should I ask another question?

Comment: Zarko's answer probably covers that (mine doesn't it can't be fixed it would be a completely different answer) @Pseudonym123

Answer (score 0):

With use of the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec={Q[c,mode=dmath]},
                 row{1} = {mode=text},
                 rowsep = {3pt}
                 }
Gobbledygook        \\
\frac{a}{b}         \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]